# Difference between Guard and Compass watch

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass, guard

These are both Ruby gems. They watch for filesystem changes. I've looked for resources detailing the aspects of each and I haven't found any that compare/contrast the two. Are these essentially the same thing just different flavors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well **Guard** is a general tool for filesystem changes that *can* be used to compile compass/sass, whereas **compass watch** is a standalone tool that watches only compass changes and isn't used for anything else.

So if all you want to watch is compass files, then compass watch should do the trick. If you also want to, for example, compile coffeescript then Guard can be used to do both, but compass watch couldn't.

Comment: If I can expand on my question, what then is the advantage of using Compass over Guard? Seems like if you might use different technologies down the road, Guard would be able to handle it from the beginning, but if you start with Compass you are locking yourself in with just SASS before you have to start looking elsewhere for workflow tools which will lead you to Guard anyway.

Comment: I suppose you are right in your assumptions. Compass naturally provides the tools to compile sass/scss to css, and watch is an argument that makes it run when the files change. It does not provide tools to do anything non-compass related. So if you need more, go for Guard!

Comment: converting in either direction is relatively painless -- guard calls on the same compass/sass compiler so it really is just a matter of desired feature set -- a common stack (for me) is guard with compass + livereload -- don't need the power -- go back to compass watch with the same config.rb file guard was pointed to